# Magento special price still showing on frontend even not set on backend

Tags: magento

I'm working on a site in Magento where I didn't set any special price for products.

for example, it is showing:

> Regular Price: $755.00
>
> Special Price: $21.00

How to hide those special prices and make visible only for those products where special price is applicable? otherwise the default price should be shown.

Comment: Do a full price reindex and if the problem persists, check that you don't have any catalog rule applying to those products.

Comment: thanks javier. u save me thanx a lot